# RichFaces picklist: Fluid scrollable list/ column

Tags: css, jsf-2, richfaces

**Aim**

I want this: [Aim Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2riL.gif).

**Initial situation**

In the following example code a `rich:picklist` is used:

```
<rich:pickList id="userAuthoritiesPickList" value="#{securityBean.selectedUserAuthorities}"
  sourceCaption="sourceCaption" targetCaption="targetCaption" style="background:green" orderable="false"
  addText="addText" addAllText="addAllText" removeText="removeText" removeAllText="removeAllText">
    <f:selectItems value="#{securityBean.authorities}" var="authority" itemValue="#{authority}"
     itemLabel="#{securityBean.getLocalizedRoleName(authority.authority)}" />
</rich:pickList>
```

I get the following result: [resultPic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leYgF.png)

**Observations**:

1. The sourceList has a scrollbar because its elements are too big.
2. There is plenty of space on the right

**Aim**

1. I want the pickList to use the free space on the right, so that the scrollbar in the sourceList gets smaller or isn't even necessary. The pickList e.g. should use 70% of the space.
2. When one resizes the browser window the pickList (and the sourceList) should resize in width so that the scrollbar in sourceLists turns necessary again.

**What i tried**

*Used these resources*:

- Looked at the page width chrome devTools
- component reference
- java-doc

*Noted*:

- `rich:pickList` only tag attribute for *width* is *listWidth* which only let's you define pixel width of list elements (percentage not possible)
- if no *listWidth* is defined, the listWidth is `width: 200px`. Using

  > .rf-pick-lst-scrl{
  >     width: initial !important;
  >    }

  I was able to change it to this.
  The sourceList now is larger, but when i resize the browser window, the sourceList width does not resize. Instead there apperas a scrollbar for the whole page.
- I tried to set the *width* to percentage on severeal styleClasses. Like e.g.

  > .rf-pick-src{
  >     width: 50%
  >    }

  But that only halfs the sourceList and not the pickList, thus the space to the buttons only widen.

**Summary**: So how to get the behaviour: SourceList (pickList) should use freeSpace. If it isn't enough -> resize the sourceList? (Like in a table you could do something with `table-layout: fixed;`). Due to manually changing the page with chrome devTools `table-layout`, i got what i want. But the `table` gets generated by `rich:pickList` and i can't set css properties for them (no id, class..):

I want it like the **Aim Pic** in the beginning of this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need id or class to use CSS, especially if you know the layout is static:

```
.rf-pick > table,
.rf-pick > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3) > table {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.rf-pick > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) {
    width: 30px; /* buttons */
}
```

set listWidth to "auto" ("100%" will also work, I'll have to fix description)

Comment: Thx, that helped me a lot.